# Spanish charecters in JQuery json get

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using this code to load content from the DB when the user selects an option :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function setStore(value)
    {
        $.get("getStoreMetaInfo.php", {store_id: value, meta_type : 3},function(data){
                document.getElementById("tvaddedtext").value =  data.tv_lamp;
                document.getElementById("parttvaddedtext").value =  data.tv_part_no;
           }, "json");
    }

</script>
```

in getStoreMetaInfo.php I'm doing a select from the DB and creating associative array and doing json_encode :

```
$meta=mysql_fetch_array($result_meta);
$result = array("tv_lamp"=>$meta['tv_lamp'],"tv_part_no"=>$meta['tv_part_no'],      
"projector_lamp"=>$meta['projector_lamp'],"projector_part_no"=>$meta['projector_part_no']);
$out = json_encode($result);
echo $out;
```

When the text I get from the DB is in English everything is working fine, but when I get spanish charecters for example the array $result looks like this (when using var_dump):

```
array(4) {
  ["tv_lamp"]=>
  string(40) "%BRAND_PROJECTOR_MODEL% TV de la L�mpara"
  ["tv_part_no"]=>
  string(32) "%BRAND_PARTNUM% TV de la L�mpara"
  ["projector_lamp"]=>
  string(44) "%BRAND_PROJECTOR_MODEL% Lamparas Proyectores"
  ["projector_part_no"]=>
  string(37) "%BRAND_PARTNUM%  Lamparas Proyectores"
}
```

and the json object I get looks like this (in firebug response):

```
{"tv_lamp":null,"tv_part_no":null,"projector_lamp":"%BRAND_PROJECTOR_MODEL% Lamparas Proyectores","projector_part_no":"%BRAND_PARTNUM%  Lamparas Proyectores"}
```

(the first two parameters are empty)

How can I make the json encoding work with those charecters?

By the way, in the page where I'm using the "setStore" function, I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in the page head

Answer (score 0):

check the encoding on your script file it should be UTF-8.

Comment: Do you mean the file excoding in an editor? If so, I changed the excoding of both files to UTF-8 and got the same results